# Counterpart of "gutter language"

Tags: selección-de-palabras

In German we use *Gossensprache*, in English *[gutter language](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/gutter-language)* seems to be the most common synonym, but my dictionaries don't show me a spanish word for the language/jargon (often vulgar) spoken by ordinary people/teenager/kids on the street, in small groups, friend circles.

Is there a spanish expression for this kind of language?

Comment: Related : http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lunfardo

Comment: @Dr.belisarius Hablar en lunfardo no tiene nada que ver con decir mala palabras. Informate un poco más, pibe

Comment: Al op: tu pregunta es sobre las **malas palabras**. Ese término del inglés no es una *jargon spoken by ordinary people on the street*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd say for *gutter language*:

> Lenguaje vulgar

or

> Lenguaje barriobajero

As suggested by Gonzalo Medina you can also say:

> Lenguaje arrabalero

though in my opinion it's not as common as the others, at least in Spain.

Comment: Perhaps you could also add to your list *lenguaje arrabalero*.

Comment: Una cosa es usar palabras vulgares y otra muy distinta es decir malas palabras

Answer (score 2):

In Spanish you can also use "lenguaje obsceno" o "malsonante".

A esas palabras malsonantes a veces se les dice "tacos", por lo que la expresión "decir un taco" o "hablar con tacos" viene a significar "usar lenguaje obsceno o vulgar".

Answer (score 1):

Otras posibilidades:

> lenguaje **soez**
>
> **palabrotas**
>
> **garabatos**

. La tercera es, por lejos, la que preferimos los chilenos.

Comment: Esta merece ser la resupesta aceptada